# d3js highlighting sunburst path when hovering on label

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3.js, and I managed to pull together (from different examples) the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg92qqo/).

It's a typical sunburst, and I have labels in a legend.

I'd like to add the functionality that when you hover (or click) on a legend label it behaves exactly as if I was on that element (highlighting the path).

I suspect I need to add a "`.on("mouseover", XXX)`" on the following portion of code, but it's not clear to me how to complete the task

```
   g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Thank you!

Being a jsfiddle it would be immensely appreciated a fork on that jsfiddle with the answer (apart from the answer here for posterity of course) ;)

**EDIT:** I changed the link to jsfiddle as it did not show the legend properly

Comment: By legend you mean the sequence shapes that come up on hover at the top or ?

Comment: By legend, as per any graph, I mean the list of colored labels that make clear what colored elements on a graph are. So the legend in this case is the list of project and business units you have on the right, not the stuff that appear on hover (which is usually called breadcrumbs)

Comment: ok, in that case, you dont have a legend in your fiddle

Comment: You are right, sorry, for some reason it keeps on discarding my changes. Here there is a working fork: https://jsfiddle.net/atg92qqo/ (I'll also update the link above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function to get all nodes from the root parent hierarchy flatten function does the same.

```
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [],
    i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

On mouse hover of legends:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
      var nodes = flatten(myData);//get all nodes
      //find the node on which it is over
      var n = nodes.find(function(d1){ return (d1.name == d.key)});
      mouseover(n);//call the mouse over function
    }).on("mouseleave", mouseleave);
```

Next on text make them `"pointer-events", "none"` so that they don't trigger the mouse leave event on legend hovering.

```
  g.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", li.w / 2)
    .attr("y", li.h / 2)
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h5qcsftt/)

Comment: Sorry Cyril, the original jsfiddle did not show the legend, so my original question did not make sense. Now it does.

Comment: What if I have multiple same sequence with varying data? I have tried your code, but it takes only one. What I need to add so that hovering on label will highlight all multiple same sequence?

Comment: Is there a new version of this code? The current fiddle is throwing a lot of errors! Please help

Comment: strange!! i am using chrome I find no errors on my console.